# How to databind class member to href attribute for <a /> or Blazor's <NavLink />?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I cannot for the life of me figure out what the correct syntax is for binding a class member to an attribute.  Specifically in this case the href attribute for an  tag or Blazor's  tag.

What I am trying to do is this, equivalent example with Vue.js

```
<a :href="'/customers/' + customer.CustomerID">
```

How do I do this in Blazor component?

I've tried:

```
<a @bind-href="/customers/customer.CustomerID">

<a @bind-href="/customers/@customer.CustomerID">

<a href="/customers/customer.CustomerID">

<a href="/customers/@customer.CustomerID">
```

Nothing works.  CustomerID is of int type.

Comment: I don't see why this one isn't working <a href="/customers/@customer.CustomerID"> looks OK to me

Comment: @DavidMasterson - Evidently it needs to be <a href="customers/@customer.CustomerID">.  Without the leading "/".  Got it to work after I fixed that.  The issue was the href attribute was not being rendered at all when I had it set that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we've defined a Blazor Component named Customer, and we want to call it from the Index page component. You can place an anchor element in the the Index component as follow:

```
<a href="customer/@customer.CustomerID">Click me</a>
```

The value of the href attribute is a url made of two segments:
1. **customer** which stands for the name of the component. Note that it should not be preceded  with "/"

2. **@customer.CustomerID** which is a Razor expression evaluated to a customer ID. It is made of the name of an instance variable of a Customer class defined in the @code block of the Index component, and the CustomerID property. Of course you can provide the value in other ways, as for instance: `<a href="customer/1">Click me</a>`

Below is the definition of the Index component
Index.razor:

```
@page "/"

<a href="customer/@customer.CustomerID">Click me</a>
<a href="customer/2">Click me</a>

@code
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();

    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; } = 1;
        public string Name { get; set; } = "Microsoft";
    }
}
```

The following is the definition of the Customer component
Customer.razor:

```
@page "/customer"

@page "/customer/{CustomerID:int}"

<p>@CustomerID</p>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the Customer component contains two @page directives with route templates. The first directive is used when you want to route to the component without providing a customer ID, as for instance:

```
<a href="customer">Click me</a>
```

The second route template is used when you want to route to the Customer component with CustomerID parameter. Note also that the Customer component contains a public property with a Paramater attribute. This property is populated by Blazor with the parameter passed to the Customer component when it is routed to.

Your unsuccessful attempts to set the href attribute of the anchor element clearly stems from the simple fact that you are not familiar with the Routing system of Blazor, so here is a link to the docs about [Blazor routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0)... Good luck.

Comment: You would be correct in your assumption, I'm pretty new to the Blazor Framework.  It seems that I had this wrong by one character.  Removing the leading "/" from the href resolved this issue.

Answer (score 21):

When using the NavLink component (instead of a `<a>` Tag), you have to use:

```
href="@($"customer/{customer.CustomerID}")"
```

Comment: Very good point in case the problem is in "<NavLink> tag and not in the <a> tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works perfectly.  Hope this helps.

```
<a href="https://google.com?test=@TestProperty">Test</a>


@code {
    public int TestProperty { get; set; } = 999;
}
```